# Can I display an ad on YouTube channel(borderline pretending they are a sponsor)?

Tags: advertisements

So I have begun display ads for "*The Dollar Shave Club*" and "*dbrand*" on my Youtube to make it seem more like an official Youtube channel and because I like these companies.

I understand there are "false pretence" laws.  As long as I don't state that they are sponsors is this practice legal?

Answer (score 2):

You are using their trademarks without permission, and can be sued to have them removed. In practice there is probably a low chance of them bringing you to court (since your channel probably has very little impact to them) but as your channel grows bigger it is exposing itself to youtube violation strikes and will likely be struck down after a while.

Answer (score 1):

The question in Australia is: are you in trade or commerce? Would a reasonable person seeing the juxtaposition be deceived or misled?

If the answers are “yes” you are breaking the law - fines are in the millions.

Comment: I am in the USA but I assuming the laws are fairly similar. Sounds like I should be at least saying "I am not a sponsor."

Comment: @William "they are not sponsors" is more accurate, *you* would be the one being sponsored by *them*.